# .net core 3.0 Certificate authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, x509certificate, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

Recently I have migrated an API from .net core 2.2 to .net core 3.0 in order to implement an authentication using certificates.

I have followed this Microsoft documentations : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.0 to do my work. But I'm facing an issue :
When I call a controller Method decorated with an [Authorize] attribute, the certificate validation is never performed. If there is no certificate in the request's header, I get a 403 which is the required behavior, but If I put a certificate the supposed behavior should be the verification by the thumbprint, but nothing...

Here my certificate validation service :

```
public class CertificateValidationService
{
    public bool ValidateCertificate(X509Certificate2 clientCertificate, string thumbprintToChek) =>
        clientCertificate.Thumbprint.Equals(thumbprintToChek);
}
```

As said in the documentation, in StartUp.cs I have set up the following lines of code inside the **ConfigureServices** method

```
services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCertificate(options => // code from ASP.NET Core sample
            {
                options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
                options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnCertificateValidated = context =>
                    {
                        var validationService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<CertificateValidationService>();

                        if (validationService.ValidateCertificate(context.ClientCertificate, Configuration.GetValue<string>("Apim:CertificateThumbprint")))
                        {
                            var claims = new[]
                            {
                                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, context.ClientCertificate.Subject, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer),
                                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.ClientCertificate.Subject, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer)
                            };

                            context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));
                            context.Success();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            context.Fail("Invalid certificate.");
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };

                options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.Fail("Certificate not valid.");

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }

                };
            });

        services.AddCertificateForwarding(options =>
        {
            options.CertificateHeader = "X-ARR-ClientCert";
            options.HeaderConverter = (headerValue) =>
            {
                X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = null;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headerValue))
                {
                    byte[] bytes = headerValue.ToByteArray();
                    clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(bytes);
                }
                return clientCertificate;
            };
        });
```

I have also populated the **Configure** method with the following code :

```
app.UseCertificateForwarding();
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

So when I make a request to the API, the CertificateForwarding delegation is well called, but Authentication delegation, never.

However, I have tried to implement this authentication in a brand new project (just for tests) it worked perfectly.

Comment: Well, I have finished by make it work.
I Have removed all the code I have previously added.
Cleaned and rebuilt the solution, then updated the StartUp.cs and Program.cs again and it Worked. I don't understand what was wrong the first time as the code remained the same.
May be there were some problems with VS cache ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assignment to `options.Events` is done twice. This way the default implementation of `OnCertificateValidated` overwrites your eventhandler and your `CertificateValidationService` will never be called.

Combining the two eventhandlers should give the expected result:

```
options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
{
    OnCertificateValidated = context =>
    {
        // Your implementation here.
    },
    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
    {
        // Your implementation here.
    }
};
```